# Request files is undefined in node.js + Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer, body-parser, formidable

I'm trying to create **HTML form** for uploading image to server with **Node.js**. I tried to do it with **Formidable** and **Multer**. In **Formidable** I got my *Fields object* normally but *files object* was `undefined`. In **Multer** I get my `req.body` normally but `req.file` is `undefined`.

I tried to do same with **Formidable** and no express and everything worked fine, but same didn't worked with **express**

here is my backend

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

app.post('/fileupload', upload.single('testFile'), (req, res, next) => {
    const file = req.file;

    if (!file) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a file');
        error.httpStatusCode = 400;
        return next(error);
    }
    res.send(file);

});
```

and my frontend

```
<form class="upload__form" action="/fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="testFile" id="file" accept="image/*">
        <label for="file" class="hover">Choose a file <i class="fas fa-upload"></i> </label>
        <span id="err_msg"></span>
        <div class="tag-input">
            <input placeholder="Type tags..." class="input" type="text" name="query"><button class="search" type="submit"><b>Add <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></b></button>
                <p class="note">*Seperate with commas <i class="far fa-times-circle hover note-close" ></i></p>
</div>
</form>
```

The code above is with **multer**, but I also tried with **Formidale**, nothing changed

Comment: Your code works fine !!! what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get error, but when I upload file, req.file is undefined and works if(!file) case, I don't know where is problem, I run it on localhost, can it be something with it?

Comment: I tried your code and i'm getting both `req.file` and `req.body`. maybe something else is causing the problem

Comment: What can cause problem like this? maybe it is something with my localhost but I don't know what it can be

Comment: Did you test the API by using some testing tools like Postman?

Comment: No, I only tested with my front-end. How to test with postman? How can I send image(or other file) with it

Comment: You are using kraken.js?

Comment: nope, only express and multer

Comment: @VaheYavrumian If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works perfectly, what you could try is not to use a middleware instead of using a function to know if your code is returning an exception.

```
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).single('testFile');
app.post('/fileupload', (req, res, next) => {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err || !req.file) {
            // An error occurred while loading the image.
            const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
            error.httpStatusCode = 400;
            return next(error);
        }
        res.send(req.file);
    });
});
```

This way you could check if `req.file` is `undefined` or if it brings an error in the variable `err`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried this code, but it still returning Error, I can't understand where the problem is. I guess it something with my local host

Comment: @VaheYavrumian you found a solution?